# Why infinite loop on app start is caused when adding a redux state as dependency to a `useEffect` hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks

I have a rather complex React Native app, which makes it difficult to provide an expo snack or such, so I do my best to explain the problem I face:

One feature of the app is that I have an array of dummy data that a user can query through to add it to his favorite list. By using an `Autocomplete` text input component the user can add a new favorite to his list by clicking on the option in the list. This new favorite item should then be displayed.

The favorites list is stored in a redux store and is updated every minute (for styling reasons) using a `useEffect` hook.

The problem I am facing is that I need to add the favorite list state to the dependencies of the `useEffect` hook. However, when doing so, my app does not start, which seems to be caused by an infinite loop (even though I do not receive any warning or error message):
[image]

**Favorite list component**

```
const curFavorites = useSelector(state => state.userData.favorites);

//This dispatch is used to update data in a favorite item inside the `useEffect` hook
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const updateStyling = useCallback((id, attr, value) => {
    dispatch(updateFavorites(id, attr, value))
}, [dispatch]);

//The useEffect that does not fire
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('test')
    updateStyling(id, attr1, "favorite1")
}, [props.minuteCounter, curFavorites ])
```

When adding `curFavorites` to the dependencies the app does not start and the above `console.log()` does not run.

---

**Reducer handling the initialization and insertion of favorites**

```
import { INSERT_FAVORITES } from "../actions/userActions";
import { FAVORITES } from "../../data/favoritesData";

// Initial state when app launches
const initState = {
    favorites: FAVORITES
};

const userReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case INSERT_FAVORITES:
            return {
                ...state,
                favorites: [
                    ...state.favorites,
                    action.newFavorite
                ]
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default userReducer;
```

What am I missing here? Why do I have an infinite loop when initializing the app when adding the `curFavorites` as a dependency in the `useEffect` hook?

Answer (score 0):

You need take a function updateStyling inside useEffect hook.

````
    updateStyling = useCallback((id, attr, value) => {
    dispatch(updateFavorites(id, attr, value))
}, [dispatch]); ```
````

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with the `updateStyling` function. Plus: you cannot use a hook inside another hook directly.

Answer (score 0):

you are updating the state inside userReducer() and same state has passed as the dependency to the useEffect().

useEffect() hook calls every time when there's a change in the dependencies. You should not use state as a dependency as it cause infinite loop

Comment: Ok. I found out that (when commenting out the `updateStyling(id, attr1, "favorite1")` line), the code works as expected. But what would be the strategy now to have both functionalities: (1) the ability to update the favorites' styling on every minute and (2) listening to changes of the favorites list state when a user adds a favorite to the list and thus again trigger style changes?